# with Catalyst framework, how to check the uri path in wrapper.tt

Tags: frameworks, catalyst

I like to check the path in wrapper.tt, so I can dynamically include links based on the path.  But I can't figure out the way to get the path in the tt file after extensive online search.  For example, I can check if a user has signed in and, if yes, show the user's name as the following.  Thanks.

```
[% IF c.user_exists %]
    <h4 style="float:right;">[% c.user.username %] <a href="/logout">logout</a></h4>
[% ELSE %]
    <h4 style="float:right;"><a href="/login">login</a></h4>
[% END %]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.  c.req.path is the uri path.